# Custom wordpress head for one page

Tags: wordpress, head

I am implementing an HTML5 map on a WordPress page.

The creator tells me I have to add some custom script to the head section of my WordPress site.

However I don't want the script to be run on every page, but just the one page.

jQuery:

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.0.0-beta1/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Scripts:

```
<link href="lg-map/map.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script src="lg-map/raphael.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="lg-map/scale.raphael.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="lg-map/lg-map.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

What's the easiest way to call this just for the one page?  I have tried to create a custom page-template and custom header call but failed due to my knowledge of PHP and how WordPress calls things.

Also, I'm not sure if I have to load the jQuery line as I read that most WordPress has this loaded in?

Answer (score 0):

You should enqueue the script using the following code it your functions.php file. If you have purchased a theme you should put this in your child theme folders functions.php.

```
function my_scripts_method() {
    //Replace 222 with the ID of the page where you want to have this added.
    if( is_post( '222' ){
        wp_enqueue_script( 'maps-jquery', "https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.0.0-beta1/jquery.min.js" );
    }
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'my_scripts_method' );
```

That being said this appears to be a very new version of jQuery. Wordpress has jQuery preloaded but not that version. You may find conflicts with loading this version while the other version is already there.